Retrieving the return value of a Python function
I have a Python script, and I want to be able to call one of its functions, which takes a single argument and returns a string, from a Makefile.
I tried the following:
define get_function_ret_value
    $(shell python3 -c "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '$(dir $(<path_to_py_script>))'); from $(notdir $(<path_to_py_script>:.py=)) import my_function; print(my_function(*sys.argv[1:]))" $(1))
endef

And to retrieve the return value of the function in Makefile, I only found this method:
target:
    ret_value=$$(echo $(call get_function_ret_value, <argument>)); \
    echo $$ret_value

However, for some reason, the value obtained can differ from what I get by simply running my custom script containing only the function I’m interested in:
target:
    # The output may differ from the expected one. \
    ret_value=$$(echo $(call get_function_ret_value, <argument>)); \
    # Prints the expected output to the terminal (print(my_function(<arg>)) in main) \
    ./myFunctionStandalone <arg>; \
    # Prints the expected output to the terminal \
    python3 -c "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '$(dir $(<path_to_py_script>))'); from $(notdir $(<path_to_py_script>:.py=)) import my_function; print(my_function(<arg>))"

How can I correctly capture the return value of the function in a variable?

Well, you don't say what output you expected and you don't say what output you got, so it's hard to say exactly what might be wrong.
However I don't understand why you're using the shell function (which is almost never a good idea inside a recipe: a recipe is already running in a shell so using make's shell function just adds an extra layer of complexity) and I don't understand why you're using echo.
Also, I strongly urge you to use single quotes around the Python script and double-quotes inside the script.  Remember that the shell will still interpret some special characters inside double-quotes, while single-quotes escape everything (except other single quotes).
Why not just use something simpler, like:
get_function_ret_value = python3 -c 'import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "$(dir $(<path_to_py_script>))"); from $(notdir $(<path_to_py_script>:.py=)) import my_function; print(my_function(*sys.argv[1:]))' $(1)

target:
        ret_value=$$($(call get_function_ret_value, <argument>)); \
        echo $$ret_value

Then look very carefully at the output make shows you when it runs the rule to be sure it's correct.  You should be able to copy/paste that command to a shell prompt and run it there and it should work.
